# Connecting to Power BI dataset using XMLA endpoint using User's Bearer\Access Token

Tags: c#, powerbi, xmla, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to connect to a Power BI Dataset hosted in Power BI Premium Workspace using below code. I don't have any issues in connecting to it when I use a SPN ID and a Secret, however when I try to use a Bearer token of the user I get below issue

Cubes = 'connection1.Cubes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

on the third last line (var connection1), My intent is to run a DMV query on the dataset and print the results in console. DMV query - 'Select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES'

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
   string tenantId = "tenantId";
   string workspaceName = "workspaceName";
   string datasetName = "datasetName";

   string accessToken = "abc" //Assume that I am able to get the bearer token programmatically 
   string xmlaEndpoint = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/groups/{workspaceName}/datasets/{datasetName}/";
   var connection1 = new AdomdConnection($"Data Source={xmlaEndpoint};User ID=;Password={accessToken};");
  }
}
```

Cubes = 'connection1.Cubes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.  Have validated the access token and it seems to be correct. I think I am doing something wrong with xmla endpoint.

Comment: Probably either the access token is incorrect (ie generated for the wrong scope), or the user doesn't have access to the Dataset.